# Date range search + Copy files

Tags: powershell

I have the below code which im trying to run based on user parameters inputted but nothing is copying over to the destination folder? Also is there a way to output on the screen when the copy is complete?

User is entering start date as: **15/11/2018** and 
User is entering end date as: **27/11/2018**

```
$start_time = Read-Host "Enter Start Date"
$end_time = Read-Host "Enter End Date"
$StrSource = Read-Host "Enter Source Path"
$des_folder = Read-Host "Enter Destination Path"

Get-ChildItem $StrSource -Recurse | foreach {
    if ($_.LastWriteTime.Date -ge $start_time.Date -and $_.LastWriteTime.Date -le $end_time.Date) {
        Copy-Item $_.FullName $des_folder
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo, the name are the same and still doesn't work.

Comment: `Read-Host` returns a _string_, not a datetime object. [*grin*] so your `$start_time.Date` will not work unless you convert the string into a datetime object. take a look at the results of a search on `powershell datetime parseexact()` for how to do it.

Comment: this solved the date issue: Get-Date (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the start date:')

I see the script copies folders where the start and end date falls in but when i go to the actual files within the folder the modified date is different. Is there a way to add to the script which only copies when the files are between the date and not the folder?

Comment: i don't know what you mean by `when the files are between the date and not the folder` ... [*blush*]

Comment: what i mean is the folder which is copied over the modified date is reflecting todays. Would it be possible to copy the folder but keeping the existing date. I think i know why it has today's date due to the folder not existing in the source directory.

if i i pipe it through robocopy will it keep the existing modified date instead of changing to today?

Comment: i haven't tested with robocopy - i recommend you do it to see what you get. [*grin*] plus, if there are a large-ish number of files, using robocopy is almost always faster. ///// however, you can change the `.LastWriteTime` info on a dir by using `Get-Item` to get the dirinfo and then setting the time to what ever you want. this `$Test.LastWriteTime = Get-Date '2001-01-01'` will set the timestamp of the dir loaded into `$Test` to the date shown.